# How to remove horizontal scroll in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Today, I have a problem with bootstrap.

Like this image.

[image]

I want to remove horizontal scroll in grid bootstrap.

I think a problem is: I tried to add a slide image with new `div.container > div.row` contain a child `div.container > div.row` and I think this problem..

My code like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row"></div> <!-- /.row contain image slider-->
        </div> <!-- /.container contain image slider -->
    </div> <!-- /.row contain content of page-->
</div> <!-- /.container contain content of page-->
```

But I don't know how to fix this.

You can see my pen at here:

http://codepen.io/r0ysy0301/pen/zKoPAE

Comment: You shouldn't be adding `.container` inside a `.row`. Why are you even using the grid layout?

Comment: and you can't have a `.row` inside a `.row` without it being in a grid column, grid markup should be the immediate child of `.row`

Comment: I know. Thanks @Zanderwar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't insert a container **INSIDE** a container without changing its width. The container itself has min-width. Reference: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

If you badly want to use a container, then use container-fluid.

Reference: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-fluid

This is the edited html codes. Hope it helps.

http://www.bootply.com/IsEptxFAGG

Comment: Great explain. I have many time with this. You save my life. Thank you very much.

Comment: @sandalkeyak, I also remove vertical scrollbar. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: simply remove **setHeight function** in your javascript.

Comment: I know that. My problem is: have anything to fixed two columns height. I don't want vertical scrollbar. If remove `setHeight` function height of two columns, not equals. I want to like the library: jquery-match-height.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you have 2 nested `.container` div elements within your `.tab-pane` element. The `.container` class has a mediaquery that sets its width explicitly which makes it larger than the `tab-pane`.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container {
    width: 1170px;
}
```

You can probably fix it a couple of different ways:

1. You can change the overflow on the `.tab-pane` from `overflow-y: auto` to `overflow-x: hidden` which isn't really a great solution because it simply cuts the content off.

-- OR --

2. You could use a different class instead of the `.container` so that you are not bound to all of its explicit widths at different breakpoints.

Comment: Good solution for my problem. Thanks.

Comment: `overflow-x: hidden!important` solved my problem, thanks

Answer (score 6):

Just define class of layout fluid, and the horizontal scrool bar is removed

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was I had a long number so that it couldn't be text-wrapped since there was no space between. I put `text-break` to class and fixed the text-wrapped issue. You can find the documentation here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/text/#word-break